# Lodash: difference function, but based on JSON format

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var b = ["text1", "text2"];
var a = [
    {name: "text3", value: 2}, 
    {name: "text4", value: 7}, 
    {name: "text1", value: 4}
];
```

There is a variety of Lodash functions that I tried, but none of them returning what I want to achieve.

What I want is:

```
var c = ["text1"]; // uniques from a compared to b
var d = [
    {name: "text3", value: 2}, 
    {name: "text4", value: 7}
]; // uniques from b compared to b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var c = _.reduce(a, (accumulator, item) => {
  if(b.indexOf(item.name) !== -1)
    accumulator.push(item.name)

  return accumulator
}, [])

var d = _.filter(a, (item) => b.indexOf(item.name) === -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the array and push not unique items.

```js
var b = ["text1", "text2"],
    a = [{ name: "text3", value: 2 }, { name: "text4", value: 7 }, { name: "text1", value: 4 }],
    c = [],
    d = a.filter(({ name }) => !b.includes(name) || !c.push(name));
  
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: WOW, just awesome. Hats off.